# How to query a MongoDB collection with a regex?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query a collection and want to do it on just the beginning of the postal code.  I've tried following the instructions but get 0 documents:

```
> db.listings.count({"house.postalcode" :  "EH21 8RG"})
2
> db.listings.count({"house.postalcode" :  {"$regex" : "/^EH21/"}})
0
```

I know I must be missing something but I've checked the regex online and you can see the results above of the two queries.. help!

Comment: When using `$regex` remove either remove string quotes (to make it a regex expression) and use : `{"$regex" : /^EH21/}` or use the string quotes without the forward slashes: `{"$regex" : "^EH21"}` [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on what driver/library you use, but this works for me:

```
db.listings.count({ "house.postalcode": /^EH21/ })
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you! :-)    > db.listings.count({"house.postal_code" :  /^EH21/})
471